# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515

Tags: android, emulation

I am facing this error message since 2 days.

```
Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515
```

These are all the steps I tried:

1. To change the RAM size of the emulator
2. To wipe data and cold boot
3. To invalidate the caches and Restart
4. To increase the size of the virtual memory

Answer (score 0):

Even I just faced the same issue.

> THE ISSUE IS BECAUSE OF **msvcp140.dll** file in system32 folder
>
> **ADD `msvcp140.dll`, `msvcp140_1.dll` and `msvcp140_2.dll` in
>   *C:\Windows\System32* (64-bit system) or in *C:\Windows\SysWOW64* (32-bit
>   systems)**
>
> After that RESTART the system.

You can download msvcp140.dll and replace that in the folder, but it didn't work for me.

What I did was -> 
In command prompt I typed *where msvcp140.dll* and the file was present in 2 locations, 1] system32 & 2] Python folder.

I replaced the one in system32 folder with the one present in python folder.
Also I added  msvcp140_1.dll and msvcp140_2.dll

Comment: Yes you are correct. After installing msvc error solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have Windows Media Pack installed, this is required to run emulator, it's not documented and not may users notice, I have Windows 11 Enterprise N which is the N variant that does come without Media Pack and emulator didn't work until I installed it.

Apps > Optional Features > Add feature > Windows Media Pack.